# Self-learning; Physics and Mathematics

Tags: physics, self-learning

My fields of interest are Physics and Mathematics. Gerard t'Hooft, 1999 Physics Noble Prize Laureate, has suggested a better scheme to study physics online. I can't wait for the university, so I've decided to start studying physics myself through his scheme. I think that the primary step should be to consolidate the primary mathematics. But I want to go on with the elementary calculus course, and electronics (Physics). I want suggestions on how should I plan the time-table? Should I learn one subject per day or all the three per day? Any additional relevant suggestions would be greatly valued.

Comment: "electronics"? You mean electromagnetics?

Comment: what I mean by electronics is this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronics

Answer (score 1):

Get a calculus textbook and work through it. I personally like R. Adams & C. Essex, James Stewart, Ron Larson, Spivak and Thomas calculus textbooks. Most calculus is useful in physics so learning it will definitely be useful.